# Lua script with multi operations not working in redis

Tags: lua, redis

Just started playing with lua scripting in redis, I want to execute the following commands in a script:

```
set k1 foo
set k2 bar
```

## Tried..

```
> EVAL "redis.call('set', KEYS[1],'foo'); redis.call('set',KEYS[2],'bar'); return 1;" 1 k1 2 k2
```

```
 > script load "redis.call('set', KEYS[1],'foo'); redis.call('set',KEYS[2],'bar'); return 1;"
 > "bb031c00b6ab2508bbf182dadd5c9bf1675cce56"
 > EVALSHA "bb031c00b6ab2508bbf182dadd5c9bf1675cce56" 1 k1 2 k2
```

## Results

```
get k1
1) "foo"

get k2
(nil)
```

Why is `k2` not set; is the script and/or syntax not correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the way you call it now, it passes in one key name (`k1`) and two arguments (`2`, `k2`).

I think you want it to be

```
EVAL "redis.call('set', KEYS[1], 'foo'); redis.call('set', KEYS[2],'bar'); return 1;" 2 k1 k2
```

Comment: The number of arguments has to be set explicitly? In this case, 2?

Comment: the number of keys has to be sent (http://redis.io/commands/eval) and arguments are everything that follows the keys.